# Violation of OO Guiding Principle

Tags: java, oop

It is said that the following code violates the OO Guiding Principle.

```
public class Main {
   public static String NAME = "James";

   public Main() {
      System.out.println("Name is: "+NAME);
   }
}

public class AnotherMain() {
   public AnotherMain() {
      System.out.println("Print name: "+Main.NAME);
   }
}
```

All I could guess is it could have an abstract class that has a concrete method of say print(String message) and then have the Main class and AnotherMain class to extend the abstract class and then pass their to-be-printed message into the print() method implemented in their parent abstract class. Then in their constructors, they would call print("Name is: "+NAME). This would save the constructors from calling System.out.println() twice.

But I am still sceptical because it says that the code has something that violates the OO Guiding Principle.

Any suggestions for this?
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right off the top of my head,

```
System.out.println("Print name: "+Main.NAME);
```

violates encapsulation by accessing something owned by an independent class; if that is intended, then `NAME` should be independent of both classes and imported into both their scopes.

Comment: What do you mean that it should be independent of both classes and imported into both their scope? Do you mean like both the Main class and AnotherMain class should have its own public static String Name = "James"? If this is the case, wouldn't this causes more changes when we need to change the name to other value?

Comment: I was speaking somewhat generically. You would have an additional class; either both `Main` and `AnotherMain` inherit from that class (not really recommended), or that class defines a `public` "get" method for the value and both `Main` and `AnotherMain` use that method to access the value. Point being that shared information should be part of a well defined shared context, instead of cherry-picking from wherever it's been stashed. Keep related values together and independent of unrelated things (including metadata such as entry points/`main`).

Comment: oh..Thanks! What happens if the public static String is intended as a public constant? Say like public static final String MOVE_EVENT = "event_move" kind of constants? Accessing the constant through a getter method feels funny, wouldn't it?

Comment: It "feels funny" initially; but the abstraction of a getter means you can change the representation or implementation later without rewriting existing users.

Comment: hmm...this reminds me of something. I also see in Java's SWT, it has its constants like SWT.ICON_WARNING, SWT.APPLICATION_MODEL. These are essentially public constants too that is used in other part of the SWT library and not from a getter method too. Why is this okay then?

Comment: A number of reasons:  The "getter" abstraction is a more recent evolution of the OO model; `public` constants used to be seen as more acceptable, and in Java `public final` constants are still fairly common as (a) performance tweaks (b) `final` constants aren't seen as being as likely to be changed in ways that the getter abstraction helps with; and something like SWT is seen as sufficiently "core" that major changes that would break such constants would cause bigger problems than the getter abstraction would help with.

Comment: cool! I see... I am not aware of this recent evolution of OO model. Thanks for telling! Thanks a lot!

Comment: When I say "recent" I'm talking relatively; it's close to 10 years old at this point, I believe. But SWT is also fairly "old" technology, so there's a fair amount of legacy stuff that can't really be changed now (my last point above).

Answer (score 1):

The violation is that one class shall not access the attribute of another class, or only via a getter.

But another OO principle is encapsulation, which usually disallow the use of public attributes.

IMO, if attributes of a class are public, then using it from another class isn't an OO violation, but it's the sign of a badly designed class.

Comment: But what happens if the public static String is intended as a public constant? Like often, I see codes writing it like public static final String MOVE_EVENT = "event_move" this kind of things? Getting such constants via a getter method would seem kinda troublesome.

Comment: To be a public constant, the static property should be immutable once set. In your example it is not the case, so either a static public getter must be created, along with setting the static property visibility to private, or, if the language allows it, declare the property as immutable/constant. I don't remember Java well enough to tell if final make a property immutable, but in C++ and C# there the `const` keyword.